# C++ order of type modifiers

Tags: c++, templates

In C++ we have template functions. For example:

```
template<class A,class B>
void something(A a, B b){
     //do something
}
```

How does the compiler guess the modifiers of types A and B? They could be A, A&, const A& etc...
What are the criteria it uses to pick the type modifiers? Is it specified by the standard?

Comment: What? What do you mean. The programmer specifies the modifiers. Template system does not change anything. This question does not make much sense to me. What does "pick up type modifiers" mean?

Comment: it's not a guessing business although C++11 auto has changed things in some places (but mostly everything is still the same). if `void something(A a, B b)` is declared, you cannot pass `const A` or `const &A` because you are violating your signature. Templates work on the basis that you are using "Generics" instead of specifics in your design pattern. Compiler looks at the definition and simply maps the implementation. If you have silly things like syntatical erros, signature mismatch, type mismatch, compiler will of course shout out loud.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the standard has some rather complex rules on type deduction. They are far too long to quote here, but hopefully knowing that the behaviour is specified precisely by C++ itself is enough to satisfy you. Note that the rules are pretty much the same for `auto`.